Very close Image placement in horizontal layout
I need this image looking Label-1,2 and 3 . I want to position them very close to each other on one axis, but they start from very distant points. I tried left-right alignment in the interface, but it didn't work. How can I solve this? I couldn't find a solution

But when I place the label like this in Qt designer:

with this code :
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter, QPen, QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


from placement_ui import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect, QPoint
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.label1 = QPixmap("images/boxView.png").scaled(300, 300)
        self.ui.label.setPixmap(self.label1)

        self.label2 = QPixmap("images/boxView.png").scaled(300, 300)
        self.ui.label_2.setPixmap(self.label2)

        self.label2 = QPixmap("images/boxView.png").scaled(300, 300)
        self.ui.label_3.setPixmap(self.label2)

        self.setPaddingAndMargin(self.ui.label)
        self.setPaddingAndMargin(self.ui.label_2)
        self.setPaddingAndMargin(self.ui.label_3)


    def setPaddingAndMargin(self,member):

        member.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        member.setStyleSheet("QLabel { padding: 0px; }")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)


    window = MainWindow()
    window.showMaximized()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

I get this result:

How can I solve this problem?

Right click on widget (not the labels) and select "center horizontally" from the alignment submenu. Alternatively, try with self.ui.widget.layout().setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter).
